# JpaRepository custom @Query generates unwanted CROSS JOIN

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

account entity code:

```java
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private User user;
```

user entity code:

```java
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Account> account = new ArrayList<>();
```

the repository cusotom method query annotion

```java
@Query(value = "FROM Account a WHERE (:userId IS NULL Or a.user.id = :userId))
```

It generates this query:

```sql
from account account0_ cross join user user1_ where account0_.user_id=user1_.id and (? is null or user1_.id=?)
```

It worked fine before I updating springboot from 2.1.4.release to 2.6.5

which is expected to be the following:

```sql
from account account0_ WHERE (:userId IS NULL Or account0_.user_id = :userId)
```

Don't know if it's due to the version change or not.

Can someone give some clues?

Answer (score 0):

It's a stange behavior on JPA if you use

```java
 @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

this above annotion,
remove this will behave normally.

Comment: more at https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/using-outer-join-in-hql-to-search-for-entities-in-hibernate/